# become_user with command sudo rootsh -i -u root , ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a question about how to run commands as root. The playbook is really simple, create a folder and after that change the owner and group

```sh
  - name: install-home-db | Create scatch directory only if it is needed
    become: yes
    file:
      path: "{{ scratch_patch }}/oracle_{{ db_version | replace('.', '_') }}"
      mode: 775
      owner: "{{ oracle_user }}"
      group: "{{ oracle_group }}"
      state: directory
    register: oracle_medias
```

The folder is created whitout problem, the problem comes when it wants to setup the user and group

In remote server I do not have permissions to run any sudo command, but I can become root user if launch command

```sh
sudo rootsh -i -u root
```

Please notice that I only can become root if use this exact command, if I run only

```sh
sudo rootsh -u root
```

It does not work and returns

```sh
Sorry, user fcruzloz is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/rootsh -u root' as root on dcplnx22121944.
```

So how could I run command using root user?
I have tried setting below paramters in ansible.cfg

```sh
[defaults]
host_key_checking             = false
# ask_pass                    = True
inventory                     = inventory/hosts
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = true
remote_user                   = fcruzloz
executable                    = /bin/bash
timeout                       = 50


[privilege_escalation]
become_exe                    = sudo rootsh
become_user                   = root
become_flags                  = -i
```

But it is still failing because permissions, when running ansible command with -vvv, I think the culprit line is below one

```sh
<2a00:da9:2:21ca:111:0:427:1> SSH: EXEC ssh -o ControlMaster=no -o ServerAliveInterval=50 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="fcruzloz"' -o ConnectTimeout=50 -tt 2a00:da9:2:21ca:111:0:427:1 '/bin/bash -c '"'"'sudo rootsh -i  -u root /bin/bash -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-eybzqcaxfeytghcwykijkpeqdlpzphdq ; /usr/bin/python /home/admin/fcruzloz/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570663425.52-9612101629719/AnsiballZ_file.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
```

And that makes sense when checking errors in /var/log/messages

```sh
2019-10-09T16:24:15.472458-07:00 dcplnx22121944 sudo: fcruzloz : command not allowed ; TTY=pts/14 ; PWD=/home/admin/fcruzloz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root /bin/bash -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-eybzqcaxfeytghcwykijkpeqdlpzphdq ; /usr/bin/python /home/admin/fcruzloz/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570663425.52-9612101629719/AnsiballZ_file.py
2019-10-09T16:24:15.625928-07:00 dcplnx22121944 sshd[16027]: Connection closed by 2a00:da9:ffa0:8601::2
```

If I run the ansible command directly in server, I mean something like below (It is not exactly same command), it fails

```sh
fcruzloz@dcplnx22121944:/home/admin/fcruzloz> sudo rootsh -i  -u root /bin/bash -c 'echo test'
Sorry, user fcruzloz is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root /bin/bash -c echo test' as root on dcplnx22121944.
```

I guess I need to do something like redirect the command to the new root shell but I could not do this, I tried with openvt but I did not get it

So do you have some idea?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help

My control maching is below linux flavor

```sh
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12-SP2"
VERSION_ID="12.2"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP2"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12:sp2"
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried 'become_user'

```
  become: yes
  become_method: su
  become_user: root
```

refer to [link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) to understand privilege escalation methods in ansible.

Comment: That does not work, please check this issue reported in ansible https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/49625